# Ruby on Rails - search function not returning results on one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm implementing a 'where' search in my Rails application, and it's able to search on all database columns except one of them. I've looked into this for quite a while, but can't figure out why it's happening.

I've currently built the search action entirely in my controller, as follows:

```
def search_results
    keywords = "%"+params[:search_keywords]+"%"
    @found_prospects = Prospect.where("current_role LIKE ?", keywords)
end
```

In my view, a user searches via a form:

```
<%= form_tag search_results_path, method: 'get' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_keywords %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

And then a table is generated using the @found_prospects variable above, as below.

```
<% @found_prospects.each do |prospect| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= prospect.id %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.source %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.first_name %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.last_name %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.country %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.city %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.current_role %></td>
       <td><%= prospect.expertise_description %></td>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

My issue is: the current_role column in my db appears to return no results on this output, even when I can see it *should* be returning results.

I've tested other columns using the exact code above with 'current_role' replaced with other terms, and it works fine. On searching with current_role, no error is produced - there are simply no results returned.

Here are the database columns in my schema:

```
  create_table "prospects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "current_role"
    t.string   "expertise_description"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.string   "source"
    t.string   "expertise_tags",        default: [],              array: true
```

I've spent a while searching for anything unusual about the current_role column, but cannot see any issue on the face of things.

Any thoughts on potential solutions would be really welcome - in fact even ideas for additional things I can do to troubleshoot would be useful.

I'm using Rails 4.2.1, and Postgres for my db.

EDIT:

I have not found a solution to this problem, but a functional workaround has been to create an identical database column called current_position, and to replace references to current_role with current_position. So far this works, though of course it's not a real fix.

Comment: What if you use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I just tried it, but it didn't make the difference unfortunately. I've also tested to ensure my search queries are in the same case as the db entries, but the same problem persists.

Comment: Have you checked it on console? can you try something like: `Prospect.where("prospects.current_role ILIKE ?", keywords)`

Comment: That's an interesting question. I hadn't tried that in fact, but doing it now it seems to *work* in Rails console. Any idea why the code might work in console but not in the application?

Comment: Either the `:search_keywords` is empty or your code for generating table is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. :search_keywords is not empty, so that would imply it's a problem with the table. Any tips for what sort of issues it could be / how I could dig to figure that out?

Comment: Can you put the code for generating the table?

Comment: I've now done this and pasted it above (just under "And then a table is generated"...). However, I feel it's unlikely this will be the issue. To debug this I also have my view displaying a count of @found_prospects which on any search on current_role returns 0. Is there anything else I should be trying? The only fix I've had so far is to create a new column called current_position and replace the current_role references with that; this works, but it's frustrating not to solve the problem properly.

Comment: When you look at `to_sql` for your query and run the result in your database, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, it seems to work in postgres (and in active record); something seems to be going wrong after that point.

Comment: Are there any gems in your app that attempt to provide authorization functionality and exposes a `current_role` method that might be interfering with your model's property name? (Or maybe Rails itself, can't check now.)

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. I'm using Pundit, and there is authorization on the page. The same problem persists when the obvious authorization for the action, but I wonder if Pundit is exposing a current_role method or attribute that's interfering here. If so, I suppose renaming the column might be the most practical solution to avoid unnecessary overlap.

Comment: Weird issues like that usually end up being a naming conflict for me - try renaming the column.

Comment: If it's an interfere issue, the code that I posted on third comment should fix it. You have to simply mention the table name before the column.

Comment: Just tried that, and it did indeed solve it. I stuck with the new column name in any case, to avoid potential interference elsewhere. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the commenters helped solve my problem, but I'm summarizing the answer below to help any who come across a similar issue.

There appeared to be a conflict with the current_role field (I believe caused by Pundit), which caused the column in my Prospect table to be ignored.

This was solved by stating the table explicitly in the code, e.g.

```
Prospect.where("prospects.current_role ILIKE ?", keywords)
```

To avoid future such conflicts, however, I have renamed the column current_position.